# Oracle loadjava error during loading of .jar

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, loadjava

I'm trying to load and publish a .jar into my Oracle database with this command:

```
loadjava -schema PIN75 -u username/password -v -resolve -debug BIPExtension.jar
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
arguments: '-u' 'username/***' '-schema' 'PIN75' '-v' '-resolve' '-debug' 'BIPExtension.jar' 
creating : resource PIN75.META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
loading  : resource PIN75.META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Error while creating "PIN75".CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE
    ORA-60019: Creating initial extent of size 14 in tablespace of extent size 8

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-60019: Creating initial extent of size 14 in tablespace of extent size 8

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1132)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1035)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.executeForDescribe(T2CStatement.java:916)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.executeForRows(T2CStatement.java:1159)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1115)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1733)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:296)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.JdbcOperations.executeDDL(JdbcOperations.java:583)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaState.createTable(LoadJavaState.java:546)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaState.getLoadLOB(LoadJavaState.java:577)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.SchemaObject.load(SchemaObject.java:845)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.ClientSchemaObject.create(ClientSchemaObject.java:307)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.SchemaObject.process1(SchemaObject.java:253)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:556)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.addObject(LoadJava.java:535)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:474)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:403)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.addJar(LoadJava.java:880)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:456)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:403)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:372)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:786)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.processDeferredFiles(LoadJava.java:648)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.process(LoadJava.java:1016)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.command(LoadJava.java:278)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.run(LoadJavaMain.java:186)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.main(LoadJavaMain.java:71)
Caused by: Error : 60019, Position : 0, Sql = create table "PIN75".CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE (name varchar2(700) unique, lob blob, loadtime date), OriginalSql = create table "PIN75".CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE (name varchar2(700) unique, lob blob, loadtime date), Error Msg = ORA-60019: Creating initial extent of size 14 in tablespace of extent size 8

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1141)
    ... 27 more
Error while getLoadLOB PIN75
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1132)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1035)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.executeForDescribe(T2CStatement.java:916)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.executeForRows(T2CStatement.java:1159)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1115)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1733)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:296)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.JdbcOperations.executeDDL(JdbcOperations.java:583)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaState.getLoadLOB(LoadJavaState.java:581)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.SchemaObject.load(SchemaObject.java:845)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.ClientSchemaObject.create(ClientSchemaObject.java:307)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.SchemaObject.process1(SchemaObject.java:253)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:556)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.addObject(LoadJava.java:535)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:474)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:403)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.addJar(LoadJava.java:880)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:456)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:403)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:372)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:786)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.processDeferredFiles(LoadJava.java:648)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.process(LoadJava.java:1016)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.command(LoadJava.java:278)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.run(LoadJavaMain.java:186)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.main(LoadJavaMain.java:71)
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 20, Sql = delete from "PIN75".CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE where name='1098953594706461', OriginalSql = delete from "PIN75".CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE where name='1098953594706461', Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1141)
    ... 26 more
creating : class PIN75.oracle/com/xmlpublisher/reports/BIPExtension
loading  : class PIN75.oracle/com/xmlpublisher/reports/BIPExtension
Error while processing oracle/com/xmlpublisher/reports/BIPExtension
    Exception java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaState.getLoadLOB(LoadJavaState.java:593)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.SchemaObject.load(SchemaObject.java:845)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.ClientSchemaObject.create(ClientSchemaObject.java:307)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.SchemaObject.process1(SchemaObject.java:253)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:556)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.addClass(LoadJava.java:609)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:459)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:403)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.addJar(LoadJava.java:880)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:456)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:403)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:372)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:786)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.processDeferredFiles(LoadJava.java:648)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.process(LoadJava.java:1016)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.command(LoadJava.java:278)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.run(LoadJavaMain.java:186)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.main(LoadJavaMain.java:71)
The following operations failed
    resource PIN75.META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: creation (createFailed)
    class PIN75.oracle/com/xmlpublisher/reports/BIPExtension: creation
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1132)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1035)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.executeForDescribe(T2CStatement.java:916)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.executeForRows(T2CStatement.java:1159)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1115)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1733)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:296)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaState.resetStmts(LoadJavaState.java:782)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.reset(LoadJava.java:177)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.command(LoadJava.java:288)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.run(LoadJavaMain.java:186)
    at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.main(LoadJavaMain.java:71)
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 20, Sql = delete from "PIN75".CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE where name='1098953594706461', OriginalSql = delete from "PIN75".CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE where name='1098953594706461', Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:1141)
    ... 12 more
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing
```

I granted `CREATE ANY PROCEDURE` and `CREATE ANY TABLE` privileges to `PIN75`

The BIPExtension.jar contains a single class with four methods:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class BIPExtension {

    public static long infStrToTimet(String dateString, int nFlag) throws ParseException {
        long utc;
        return utc;
    }

    public static String infTimetToStr(int lTimeIn, int nFlag) {
        StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer();
        return sBuf.toString();
    }

    public static String infGetVersion() {
        return new String("7.5.0.0.1");
    }

    public static String infGetDateRange(int dateRange, int nFlag) {
        StringBuffer sBuf;
        return sBuf.toString();
    }

    public static String infReplicateString(String inputString, String inputMask, int inputUnmaskLength) {
        StringBuffer paramString = new StringBuffer(tempString);
        return paramString.toString();
    }
}
```

I just want to use those methods during the execution of SELECT statements. Please tell me if I'm following the wrong path. If not, please help me to fix this error during the use of the loadjava utility.

Comment: Looks like loading java into the DB involves creating a table (CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE) in the schema. It is having a problem creating that table, possibly because the user hasn't been allocated a tablespace quota (ie a chunk of space for the table to be stored in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://ora.codes/ora-60019/) they recommand to retry whith a larger tablespace.

[Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR54313) they recommand to use a tablespace with `AUTOALLOCATE`